# Проблема с нетстатом поверх adb andriod

Tags: android, linux, adb

Выполняю команду, хочу получить имена процессов, но получается такая ерунда.

```
root@ctl_iptv_mrvl:/ #  netstat -ntlp
netstat: '1828/com.android.systemui' > 21 bytes
1|root@ctl_iptv_mrvl:/ #
```

Как исправить или как получить аналогичную табличку подругому?

Comment: По настойчивому упоминанию adb напрашивается вопрос — без adb работает?

Comment: это надо терминал ставить.... а я на этом телеке грохнул ланчер и впихнул коди вместо предустановленных платных сервисов

Comment: Ну в общем на моём LineageOS 13 в терминале работает нормально, так что попробую предположить, что это какие-то заморочки конкретно этого телека